# Open a new tab with Link in React

Tags: reactjs

I have this React code:

```
<Link target="_blank" to='https://www.linkedin.com/in/n....../'>
  <i className='fab fa-linkedin-in'></i>
</Link>
```

I want to open a new tab with a custom link. But I I'm redirected to:

```
http://localhost:3000/about-us/https://www.linkedin.com/in/ni..../
```

Do you know why I'm not redirected to `https://www.linkedin.com/in/ni..../` and how I can fix it?

Comment: "Custom link?" Does that mean you wrote custom logic to do the redirect? That would be the place to look.

Comment: Are you using Next.js?

Comment: I use `import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';`. I use React.

Comment: Why not just use a regular `<a>` tag? It's an external link, not within your SPA

Comment: If possible I would like to use `Link`

Comment: The source for the `Link` component is [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/c47464c7e51c38cdf21a9fc2db81248daee2d171/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L879). It appears capable of handling an external link, this may be a bug in the package. Perhaps open an issue on that Github repository.